# How do i make a class as such that it could be assigned a value using an equal sign

Tags: class, object, equals, assign

first why i am trying to do this...well i am trying to learn programming and think that understanding this step will further help me. So please help.
As can be done with int in several languages...

**int x;**

**x=2;**

so how can i do this:

**abc x;**

**x=2;**

fill this in

**class abc{**

*//"what do i do here to make whatever object that is created out of it to be able to have value assigned in that manner... not like abc(2); this i can do."*

**}**

Solution:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ABC {
    private:
        int x;
    
    public:
        
        int getX() const  {
            return this->x;
        }
        
        ABC(int y) {
         this->x = y;
        }
    

        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outputStream, const ABC& p);
        
    
        ABC operator=(const int &b) {
            this->x = b;
            return this->x;
        }
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outputStream, const ABC& p){
    outputStream << p.getX();
    return outputStream;
}
        

int main() {
    ABC s = 1;
    std::cout << s << "\n";

    s = 4;
    std::cout << s << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to pick a language here.

Comment: That doesn't work in every language. C++?

Comment: choose whichever language you want...how about C++ or javascript

Comment: I know it could got to do something with constructors etc.

Comment: I think you are asking about passing a value to a function. You can do this with many languages such as Java, Python or Ruby. I would suggest picking a language and then clarifying your question.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. If you can edit it for clarity, please flag it for moderator attention to be reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ at least, it's implicit with a single-argument constructor. In JavaScript, it's not possible. C++:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    int x;

    SomeClass(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SomeClass s = 5;

    cout << s.x << "\n"; // 5

    s = 17;

    cout << s.x << "\n"; // 17

    return 0;
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/xWHNG9o2)

Comment: thanks i see what you did...not exactly what i wanted but still the same lol.

Answer (score 0):

Object don't quite work like that. An int can be assigned to 7, because an int is a primitive type, and 7 is a primitive type. An object is different. An object can only be assigned to an object of the same type. 7 is not an object. Its just a number.

An object is a collection of instance variables and methods. This prevents you from assigning it to a primitive type, like an int, which is just a collection of bits. The only thing an object can be assigned to, is an object of the same type, or an object cast to that type.

Comment: posted an answer